# filter results by max count(field)

Tags: mysql

here is query

```
SELECT `mpv`.`member_id` as member_id, `screen_name`, `viewed_url`, 
    count(viewed_url) as viewed_url_cnt
FROM (`tracker` mpv)
JOIN `members` m ON `mpv`.`member_id`=`m`.`member_id`
GROUP BY `viewed_url`, `member_id`
```

it returns

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------------+
| member_id | screen_name | viewed_url | viewed_url_cnt |
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------------+
|         1 | admin       | /          |              1 |
|         1 | admin       | /1         |              1 |
|         1 | admin       | /2         |              1 |
|         1 | admin       | 2          |              1 |
|         1 | admin       | 3          |              2 |
|         2 | test        | 4          |              1 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.12 sec)
```

I need to get all records which have highest `viewed_url_cnt` grouped by `viewed_url`, `member_id`. So based on results on the top, I whould like to get

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------------+
| member_id | screen_name | viewed_url | viewed_url_cnt |
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------------+
|         1 | admin       | 3          |              2 |
|         2 | test        | 4          |              1 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.12 sec)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select s1.member_id, s1.screen_name, s1.viewed_url, s1.viewed_url_cnt from (
  select t1.member_id, t1.screen_name, t1.viewed_url, count(*) viewed_url_cnt
  from tracker t1
  group by t1.member_id, t1.screen_name, t1.viewed_url
) as s1
join (
  select s2.member_id, max(viewed_url_cnt) as viewed_url_max from (
    select t1.member_id, count(*) viewed_url_cnt
    from tracker t1
    group by t1.member_id, t1.viewed_url
  ) as s2
  group by s2.member_id
) as s3
on s1.member_id = s3.member_id and s1.viewed_url_cnt = s3.viewed_url_max
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be misinterpreting what you want, but a solution would be to use an inner query to determine the appropriate `viewed_url_cnt` for each `member_id`, and then `JOIN` that to your table:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_qry outer
JOIN
(SELECT member_id, MAX(viewed_url_cnt) AS max_cnt
FROM my_qry
GROUP BY member_id) inner 
ON outer.member_id = inner.member_id AND outer.viewed_url_cnt = inner.max_cnt
```

(Here `my_qry` is the query you used to generate the original table.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the following is possible :

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY name) as foo GROUP BY dept
```

replace the inner query with your query and then you can just get the max(viewed_url_cnt) group by member_id .
Let me know if this fails..

Comment: it doesnt fails but I do not understand where to put max() in this case. Thanks